# TypeError in get_default_values

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv

How to reproduce:

- Get an up-to-date Arch Linux installation (or [Travis CI instance](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/make-includes/builds/93243223))
- Run this:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/l0b0/make-includes.git
  cd make-includes
  git checkout 643b15af0cf246ab669176b2c564bf9f88b63c0b # current HEAD
  make test
  ```

Result:

```
/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv/virtualenv-12.1.1/virtualenv.py --python=/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/Python-2.7.10-install/bin/python2.7 /tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv-2.7.10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv/virtualenv-12.1.1/virtualenv.py", line 2352, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv/virtualenv-12.1.1/virtualenv.py", line 763, in main
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 1370, in parse_args
    values = self.get_default_values()
  File "/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv/virtualenv-12.1.1/virtualenv.py", line 642, in get_default_values
    return optparse.Values(defaults)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/optparse.py", line 827, in __init__
    setattr(self, attr, val)
TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'NoneType'
python.mk:85: recipe for target '/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv-2.7.10' failed
make[1]: *** [/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv-2.7.10] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/dev/make-includes'
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'test-python-virtualenv' failed
make: *** [test-python-virtualenv] Error 2
```

Interestingly, if I run that last command again just afterwards, it works:

```
$ /tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv/virtualenv-12.1.1/virtualenv.py --python=/tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/Python-2.7.10-install/bin/python2.7 /tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv-2.7.10
Running virtualenv with interpreter /tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/Python-2.7.10-install/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv-2.7.10/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /tmp/tmp.Hwv8afXNsE/virtualenv-2.7.10/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

What gives?